# How to format the array output to 5 blocks space and other half on the next line?

Tags: java

so basically I need to print 12 given numbers in my array if the input is
    1 and random numbers if input is 2. and the format should be as below, 8 
    on one line with 5 block spacing and other 4 on the bottom of it.

> ## 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
>
> ## 9 10 11 12
>
> ```
> all the 12 numbers will be in the same array but the output must be like 
> this.
> ```

```
and if the input is 2, the array must output 12 random numbers



 all i know and read in the book is something like this to print nomally

  System.out.printf(Arrays.toString(array));
  if (i == 1){
  System.out.printf("%5s", Arrays.toString(array))   ;
 }

     int i = input.nextInt();
    int[] array = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
  System.out.printf(Arrays.toString(array));
  if (i == 1){
  System.out.printf("%5s", Arrays.toString(array))   ;
 }

  I wanted the print to be >1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 /n 9 10 11 12 
  but the output is within sets {}
```

Comment: Iterate over the elements, print them with `System.out.print`, and then every x characters, print a newline

Comment: something like this? System.out.printf("%5d, %5d, %5d, %5d, %5d\n %5d",  1,2,3,4,5,6);

Comment: Use a `for` loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the core printing with no `if` this way:

```
public class TTest1 {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        int[] array = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
        for (int i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++)
            System.out.printf("%5d%s", array[i], (i % 8 == 7)? "\n\n" : "");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Result:

```
1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8

9   10   11   12
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use scanner to get input from the user:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int i = input.nextInt();

if(i == 1) {
    int[] array = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
    for(int ind = 0; ind < array.length; ind++) {
        System.out.printf("%5d ", array[ind]);
        if(ind == 7) {
            System.out.println(); //to have 8 numbers on the first line
        }
     }
}
else {
     //write code for random number generation here
    }
```

Comment: do you mind explaining how you did it? is the loop for the space? I see how you used the >if(ind == 7) {println)();}.

Comment: The loop is simply to print each value in the array. You could do it all in one line with a long print statement, but that looks messy. The loop goes through each value in the array and prints it, while the spacing is handled with the %5 in the print statement.